# Installing an older version of terragrunt Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, github

This is my first time trying to install this package. I am on an SSH console to a VM so no GUI. I need to install version 0.18.7 which can only be accessed from the github repo page.

I downloaded it and tried to directly point to it using chmod but with no luck. I have also tried installing it with make when I download the tar.gz but I get the error "Various utilities for managing the terragrunt repository".

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry guys I'm new to Linux.

This is the link to the GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/tag/v0.18.7

Answer (score 2):

The [installation instructions](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/install/#manual-install) say

> You can install Terragrunt manually by going to the Releases Page, downloading the binary for your OS, renaming it to terragrunt, and adding it to your PATH.

Thus, the actions are:

```
$ wget https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v0.18.7/terragrunt_linux_amd64
$ mv terragrunt_linux_amd64 terragrunt
$ chmod +x terragrunt
$ sudo mv terragrunt /usr/local/bin
```